# Strapi password recovery '/forgot-password' returns 400

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I am trying to implement the password recovery functionality on my strapi app.

Following the documentation I call:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:1337/auth/forgot-password', {
      email: <MY_EMAIL>,
    })
```

though the network call gets stuck on pending for several minutes and then responds with a `400 Bad Request` error.

Did anybody experience something similar?

I checked for user permissions and the Public role has permission to `forgotpassword`. Any other configuration check I could try?

Thanks a lot,

M

Answer (score 1):

The `forgotPassword` function throws `Bad Request 400` errors for 4 possible reasons:

1. Invalid email format
2. If **no user exists** with such email in backend
3. If **the user exists** but is **marked as blocked** in backend
4. If it's unable to send a mail to the user via the email service

###### Source Code

```js
async forgotPassword(ctx) {
    let { email } = ctx.request.body;

    // Check if the provided email is valid or not.
    const isEmail = emailRegExp.test(email);

    if (isEmail) {
      email = email.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      return ctx.badRequest(
        null,
        formatError({
          id: 'Auth.form.error.email.format',
          message: 'Please provide a valid email address.',
        })
      );
    }

    const pluginStore = await strapi.store({
      environment: '',
      type: 'plugin',
      name: 'users-permissions',
    });

    // Find the user by email.
    const user = await strapi
      .query('user', 'users-permissions')
      .findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });

    // User not found.
    if (!user) {
      return ctx.badRequest(
        null,
        formatError({
          id: 'Auth.form.error.user.not-exist',
          message: 'This email does not exist.',
        })
      );
    }

    // User blocked
    if (user.blocked) {
      return ctx.badRequest(
        null,
        formatError({
          id: 'Auth.form.error.user.blocked',
          message: 'This user is disabled.',
        })
      );
    }

    // Generate random token.
    const resetPasswordToken = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

    const settings = await pluginStore.get({ key: 'email' }).then(storeEmail => {
      try {
        return storeEmail['reset_password'].options;
      } catch (error) {
        return {};
      }
    });

    const advanced = await pluginStore.get({
      key: 'advanced',
    });

    const userInfo = sanitizeEntity(user, {
      model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model,
    });

    settings.message = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.userspermissions.template(
      settings.message,
      {
        URL: advanced.email_reset_password,
        USER: userInfo,
        TOKEN: resetPasswordToken,
      }
    );

    settings.object = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.userspermissions.template(
      settings.object,
      {
        USER: userInfo,
      }
    );

    try {
      // Send an email to the user.
      await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
        to: user.email,
        from:
          settings.from.email || settings.from.name
            ? `${settings.from.name} <${settings.from.email}>`
            : undefined,
        replyTo: settings.response_email,
        subject: settings.object,
        text: settings.message,
        html: settings.message,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, err);
    }

    // Update the user.
    await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').update({ id: user.id }, { resetPasswordToken });

    ctx.send({ ok: true });
  },
```

You can check the entire source code [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/077741b03725cc981bc984399d553df8a12d89d0/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js) to understand even better. Additionally, I would suggest you to check your terminal or browser response to get more information on the error response. The response will usually contain the `message` key which will tell you why exactly this request failed.